# Access SHA-1 or Gradle tab from Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, sha

I am trying to access my project's SHA certificate fingerprint, but the steps to take from Stack Overflow do not work. Specifically, there is no Gradle tab on the right when I go to gradle.properties. There is no option for displaying it in View->Tool Windows. There is no pop up text that shows up when I select gradle.properties for opening this. There do not appear to be updated instructions for how to access Gradle tab on the right of Android Studio.

The other option I found is to get it manually, but is that the only way to do it nowadays?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only speak for Linux, but this might as well work on a Mac.

Click tab "Terminal" and then run:

```
cd android
chmod +x ./gradlew
./gradlew app:signingReport
```

Answer (score 1):

Open the Gradle Tab from here:

View -> Tool Windows -> Build.

Here you go!

OR IF THIS DOESN'T WORKS:

Seems you're working on a Flutter Project

You can right-click on project- or android-folder, select Flutter->'Open Android module in Android Studio'

[Refer this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6lIq.png)

After that the gradle-tab appears on the right and you can use it as intended.

Comment: I am not given that option. Is there a way I can do something so i am given that option?

Comment: could you share a screenshot of ur window?

Comment: Screenshot added.

Comment: Seems you're working on a Flutter Project

The problem for Android Studio is that the android(gradle)-project is not top-level. You can right-click on project- or android-folder, select Flutter->'Open Android module in Android Studio' 



[Refer this Image](https://i.ibb.co/y0ZGKxW/WKgTH.png)



After that the gradle-tab appears on the right and you can use it as intended.

Tell if this works!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it. But when I select the project that way, it only says "Open iOS module in Xcode." When I try the android folder, the flutter option is not selectable. Any advice?

Comment: That worked for producing the SHA-1 fingerprint. Thanks! Unfortunately, I still get this error when I try using Firebase Authentication: "This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [ App validation failed. ] I guess I'll double check about the package name.

Comment: Happy to Help, if this answer helped you I request you to kindly upvote and accept this answer...It helps to keep motivation up :) @michaeldebo